# Как в массив записать переменную, а не значение

Tags: java, arraylist

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть три переменные

```
private static double totalRevenueNegative = 0;
private static double totalRevenueNormal = 0;
private static double totalRevenuePositive = 0;
```

Есть ArrayList куда я хочу записать переменные (не значения)

```
ArrayList<Double> forecast = new ArrayList<>();
forecast.add(totalRevenueNegative);
forecast.add(totalRevenueNormal);
forecast.add(totalRevenuePositive);
```

Далее , у меня стоит задача, в цикле доставать из массива переменные по очереди, и присваивать им значения, но, если я в цикле использую такую запись `forecast.get(i)` - то она мне достаёт из массива значение, а именно 0.0, а нужна переменная, чтобы ей присваивать новые значения

Comment: вам нужно определить что по итогу требуется получить, если массив с новыми значениями, то обновлять их можно по индексу, если нужны новые переменные, то в чем смысл массива? если вы потом хотите использовать например элемент по индексу 0, то почему его просто не брать из массива отказавшись от переменных?

Comment: Хм.. Если вы сделаете массив из трех элементов, то A[1] позволяет присваивать значение первому элементу, т.е. A[1] как бы первая переменная, не так ли?

Comment: По итогу нужно по очереди из массива доставать переменные и присваивать им значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что double примитивный тип, и является значимым. Вам нужно создать отдельный класс с одной переменной, чтобы можно было записать ссылку в массив. Вот:

```
public class DOUBLE {
    public double doub;
    public DOUBLE(double doub){
        this.doub = doub;
    }
}
```

Записать в массив:

```
private static DOUBLE totalRevenueNegative = new DOUBLE(0);
private static DOUBLE totalRevenueNormal = new DOUBLE(0);
private static DOUBLE totalRevenuePositive = new DOUBLE(0);
ArrayList<DOUBLE> forecast = new ArrayList<>();
forecast.add(totalRevenueNegative);
forecast.add(totalRevenueNormal);
forecast.add(totalRevenuePositive);
```

Обратиться:

```
double a = forecast.get(0).doub;
double b = forecast.get(1).doub;
double c = forecast.get(2).doub;
```

Comment: какой кошмар)))

Answer (score 0):

По-моему тут **[«Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/191482)**.

Всё делается проще (отчасти).

Если у вас есть три переменные, связанные собой по контексту, то проще не определять три переменные отдельно, а сделать класс с такими свойствами и уже экземпляр класса добавлять в список, а потом вынимать его и оперировать свойствами.

---

А если планируется оперировать только тремя переменными, то зачем в принципе список? Почему нельзя просто оперировать этими переменными в коде?